# How do you find multiple planes in a 3D pointcloud?

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am looking to find all the planes in a 3D pointcloud using PCL. The example snippet has a video showing two different planes detected:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php

But if I look at the source code snippet I think it assumes that there is only one plane in the point cloud.

Is it possible to use PCL to detect all the planar sections in a point cloud using RANSAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this cluster extraction tutorial](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cluster_extraction.html). From line `44` to line `69` you can see how "all" planes are removed from the cloud. The trick is to set the filter to negative `.setNegative(true)` to extract the cloud without the planar surface.

Comment: Thank you very subtle and important step.

Comment: The link is a 404, could you please update it?